# gitweb not loading repositories through symlinks

Tags: linux, git, apache2, gitweb

I have gitweb on localhost and a sample project for which I've executed the `git init` `git add` and so on. I create a symlink with `sudo ln -s /media/dir/project/.git/ /var/cache/git/project.git` but it doesn't work and I still get `404 - no project found` at localhost/gitweb.

The only way I can only bring the project info titles such as description, ..., then without project info, only the 4 sorting options, is to copy the git physically to /var/cache/git/project.git/ though some files won't be copied. This is the only way I could only not receive the not found error.

I manipulated the `/etc/gitweb.conf` and `/etc/apache2/conf.d/gitweb` in anyway, but it didn't help.

(I'm using apache 2.2 under Kubuntu 11.10)

Thanks so much for your helps!

Comment: Anybody? No one paying attention to git? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Check the permissions on all of the directories in the symlink path. Whatever user your cgi is running as needs at least +x on all the parent dirs and +r on the .git directory and files.